# React Native rnpm unlink library

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

Recently added this library: https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker but after trying to debug the issues that I get on build, I saw that this library is unavailable for linking through rnpm and only through cocoapods. Is there any way to unlink the library using rnpm and then install cocoa pods and do it that way? I don't want to create some conflicts between the two.

The issue I'm getting with the library is `'RCTHBridgeModule.h file not found.'` and the creator of the library said he currently does not support rnpm.

Answer (score 55):

## Very easy

1. `react-native unlink lib-name-example`
2. `npm uninstall --save lib-name-example`

Comment: it still does not enough, you still need manually to remove other configurations

Comment: @AlexNguyen what do you mean like import statements? please provide examples and or edit the answer

Comment: because some libs need you manually modify the configuration file such as build.gradle,AndroidManifest etc. So you also need to remove it after running above command

Comment: if the above does not work, go to the `github` repo and from the readme, go through the manual installation and revert them.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

1. `rnpm unlink react-native-image-crop-picker` from root project directory
2. Manually install **react-native-image-crop-picker** for iOS using [these instructions](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker#ios-step-by-step-installation) (make sure you do the `pod install` step)
3. Manually install **react-native-image-crop-picker** for Android using [these instructions](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker#android-1)
4. Clean + Build :)

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to rnpm link simply add ImageCropPicker.xcodeproj from node modules it will be in ios folder just drag it and drop to your libraries folder in xcode , then after go to build phase and add libImageCropPicker.a  inside LinkBinary with Libraries folder that all you need to do for non Coca pods users